# object pool design pattern in actionscript

Tags: actionscript, object, pool

Can anyone show an example of the object pool design pattern, as written with Actionscript 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shane Mccartney wrote a blog about the object pool pattern on Lost In Actionscript, you can find it at http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/30/object-pooling-in-as3/

He posted the source of the example as well so you can just copy paste it and adjust where necessary.